# PHP - How do I get name servers from domains via WhoIs

Tags: php, dns, nameservers

I have a list of 300 domains I want to get the nameservers for.

https://github.com/regru/php-whois

I am refering to this but I am new to php and im not too sure where I set my list of domains to check through.

I want to end up with a csv file that has:
*domain name,name server, name server, nameserver*

```
    <?php

$sld = 'reg.ru';

$domain = new Phois\Whois\Whois($sld);

$whois_answer = $domain->info();

echo $whois_answer;

if ($domain->isAvailable()) {
    echo "Domain is available\n";
} else {
    echo "Domain is registered\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to get started, you should be able to loop after

```
<?php
$domain = "google.com";
$whois  = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=".$domain."&outputFormat=json"), true);

if(isset($whois["WhoisRecord"]["dataError"]) && $whois["WhoisRecord"]["dataError"]){
    echo $domain." is available\n";
}else{
    echo $domain." is not available\nNameservers: ";
    var_dump($whois["WhoisRecord"]["nameServers"]["hostNames"]);
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: did you get `google.com is not available Nameservers: NULL` as the result for this?

Comment: I keep getting null for nameservers :s

Comment: php testNSLookup.php 
google.com is not available
Nameservers: array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "ns1.google.com"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "ns4.google.com"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "ns3.google.com"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "ns2.google.com"
}

Comment: You might need to go to www.whoisxmlapi.com and get an API key.

Comment: first 500 queries are free then for 2000/month it is 15$.